# Is there a simple way to get image dimensions in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, image, osx-snow-leopard, dimensions

I'm looking for an easy way to get width and height dimensions for image files in Ruby without having to use ImageMagick or ImageScience (running Snow Leapard).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[libimage-size](http://rubyforge.org/projects/imagesize/) is a Ruby library for calculating image sizes for a wide variety of graphical formats.  A gem is available, or you can download the source tarball and extract the `image_size.rb` file.

Answer (score 53):

As of June 2012, [FastImage](https://github.com/sdsykes/fastimage) which "finds the size or type of an image given its uri by fetching as little as needed" is a good option. It works with local images and those on remote servers.

An IRB example from the readme:

```
require 'fastimage'

FastImage.size("http://stephensykes.com/images/ss.com_x.gif")
=> [266, 56]  # width, height
```

Standard array assignment in a script:

```
require 'fastimage'

size_array = FastImage.size("http://stephensykes.com/images/ss.com_x.gif")

puts "Width: #{size_array[0]}"
puts "Height: #{size_array[1]}"
```

Or, using multiple assignment in a script:

```
require 'fastimage'

width, height = FastImage.size("http://stephensykes.com/images/ss.com_x.gif")

puts "Width: #{width}"
puts "Height: #{height}"
```

Answer (score 38):

You could try these (untested):

http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/805

PNG:

```
IO.read('image.png')[0x10..0x18].unpack('NN')
=> [713, 54]
```

GIF:

```
IO.read('image.gif')[6..10].unpack('SS')
=> [130, 50]
```

BMP:

```
d = IO.read('image.bmp')[14..28]
d[0] == 40 ? d[4..-1].unpack('LL') : d[4..8].unpack('SS')
```

JPG:

```
class JPEG
  attr_reader :width, :height, :bits

  def initialize(file)
    if file.kind_of? IO
      examine(file)
    else
      File.open(file, 'rb') { |io| examine(io) }
    end
  end

private
  def examine(io)
    raise 'malformed JPEG' unless io.getc == 0xFF && io.getc == 0xD8 # SOI

    class << io
      def readint; (readchar << 8) + readchar; end
      def readframe; read(readint - 2); end
      def readsof; [readint, readchar, readint, readint, readchar]; end
      def next
        c = readchar while c != 0xFF
        c = readchar while c == 0xFF
        c
      end
    end

    while marker = io.next
      case marker
        when 0xC0..0xC3, 0xC5..0xC7, 0xC9..0xCB, 0xCD..0xCF # SOF markers
          length, @bits, @height, @width, components = io.readsof
          raise 'malformed JPEG' unless length == 8 + components * 3
        when 0xD9, 0xDA:  break # EOI, SOS
        when 0xFE:        @comment = io.readframe # COM
        when 0xE1:        io.readframe # APP1, contains EXIF tag
        else              io.readframe # ignore frame
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Ooo, sweet, goin' after the bytes directly! Old-school!

Comment: Ruby 1.9 has broken the JPEG class you cite here; I've submitted an additional answer with my modification of that class to work both under Ruby 1.8.7 and Ruby 1.9.

Comment: @ChristopheD: thanks; I'm just getting into Ruby 1.9 (using 1.9.3) and was previously using the code you'd found, so I enjoyed figuring out why that code had broken and how to fix it!

Answer (score 31):

There's also a new (July 2011) library that wasn't around at the time the question was originally asked: the [Dimensions](http://rubygems.org/gems/dimensions) rubygem (which seems to be authored by the same Sam Stephenson responsible for the byte-manipulation techniques also suggested here.)

Below code sample from project's README

```
require 'dimensions'

Dimensions.dimensions("upload_bird.jpg")  # => [300, 225]
Dimensions.width("upload_bird.jpg")       # => 300
Dimensions.height("upload_bird.jpg")      # => 225
```

Comment: This gem worked out really well for me. On the surface it doesn't do much but the internal classes are highly flexible and well-written.

Answer (score 15):

There's a handy method in the paperclip gem:

```
>> Paperclip::Geometry.from_file("/path/to/image.jpg")
=> 180x180
```

This only works if `identify` is installed. If it isn't, if PHP is installed, you could do something like this:

```
system(%{php -r '$w = getimagesize("#{path}"); echo("${w[0]}x${w[1]}");'})
# eg returns "200x100" (width x height)
```

Comment: This is great solution, it however relies on ImageMagick's `identify` tool to be installed

Answer (score 10):

I have finally found a nice quick way to get dimensions of an image. You should use **[MiniMagick](https://github.com/minimagick/minimagick)**.

```
require 'mini_magick'

image = MiniMagick::Image.open('http://www.thetvdb.com/banners/fanart/original/81189-43.jpg')
assert_equal 1920, image[:width]
assert_equal 1080, image[:height]
```

Comment: Which uses ImageMagick, which the poster asked to not use.

Comment: At least it helped me in 2018 <3

Comment: mini_magick might use ImageMagick, but it abstracts it away, so you don't actually use it yourself.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a version of the JPEG class from ChristopheD's answer that works in both Ruby 1.8.7 and Ruby 1.9. This allows you to get the width and height of a JPEG (.jpg) image file by looking directly at the bits. (Alternatively, just use the Dimensions gem, as suggested in another answer.)

```
class JPEG
  attr_reader :width, :height, :bits
  def initialize(file)
    if file.kind_of? IO
      examine(file)
    else
      File.open(file, 'rb') { |io| examine(io) }
    end
  end
private
  def examine(io)
    if RUBY_VERSION >= "1.9"
      class << io
        def getc; super.bytes.first; end
        def readchar; super.bytes.first; end
      end
    end
    class << io
      def readint; (readchar << 8) + readchar; end
      def readframe; read(readint - 2); end
      def readsof; [readint, readchar, readint, readint, readchar]; end
      def next
        c = readchar while c != 0xFF
        c = readchar while c == 0xFF
        c
      end
    end
    raise 'malformed JPEG' unless io.getc == 0xFF && io.getc == 0xD8 # SOI
    while marker = io.next
      case marker
        when 0xC0..0xC3, 0xC5..0xC7, 0xC9..0xCB, 0xCD..0xCF # SOF markers
          length, @bits, @height, @width, components = io.readsof
          raise 'malformed JPEG' unless length == 8 + components * 3
        # colons not allowed in 1.9, change to "then"
        when 0xD9, 0xDA then  break # EOI, SOS
        when 0xFE then        @comment = io.readframe # COM
        when 0xE1 then        io.readframe # APP1, contains EXIF tag
        else                  io.readframe # ignore frame
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3):

For PNGs I got this modified version of ChristopeD's method to work.

```
File.binread(path, 64)[0x10..0x18].unpack('NN')
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what is the difference between `File.binread` vs `IO.read` ?

Comment: @fatfrog `File.binread` opens the file, reads it as a binary and closes the file. `IO.read` opens the file as does not close it. Also allows you to specify the mode for reading.