# Sketchup Ruby Load external library

Tags: ruby, sketchup

I have a problem with loading externel library in Sketchup

I want to know the orginal width and height of image. But i didn't find out  in Sketchup API. So i download fastimage, a library can do it. (https://github.com/sdsykes/fastimage) . I installed it by using command:

```
gems install fastimage
```

This new gem is installed in: C:\Ruby186\lib\ruby\gems\1.8 .Then i require it in my script (by following the turorial in above link) :

```
require 'fastimage'
```

But i got the error: no such file to load -- fastimage

Then i found one solution in this link :http://sketchucation.com/forums/viewtopic.php?t=29412#p257058. Create a loadpath script ,and create a linking to external library. After creating this script, put them into plugin folder in Sketchup,and run Sketchup again. But i still get the error : No such file to load.

.

Version of my ruby is 1.8.6, and when i type command : puts RUBY_VERSION in Sketchup ruby console. Its output is 1.8.6 (the same version as my ruby). I don't understand why it can not require new gem. Please help me, thanks you.

Answer (score 1):

since you use [ruby-1.8](/questions/tagged/ruby-1.8), your should specify `require 'rubygems'` in front of your executable, so:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'fastimage'
```

If requiring the [rubygems](/questions/tagged/rubygems) throws the error, that means the [rubygems](/questions/tagged/rubygems) isn't installed in your system for current [ruby](/questions/tagged/ruby), so install it, for example as follows:

```
apt-get install rubygems
```

Comment: I added require 'rubygems' but it display the error : no such file to load -- rubygems

Comment: @Beginner it seems that the rubygems isn't installed for your ruby version, so install it.

Comment: SketchUp only ships with Ruby 1.8 Core - it doesn't include the Standard Library.

Comment: @thomthom: It's mean that , we can't use gem install command in ruby console in Sketchup.

Comment: @Beginner rubygems for ruby 1.8 shell be installed apart the ruby, additionally.

Comment: @Beginner: Yes, Ruby Gems are not available to the Ruby 1.8 bundle that ship with SketchUp.

Comment: @МалъСкрылевъ: The question relates to the version of Ruby that SketchUp embeds - which is not the complete Ruby.

Comment: @thomthom: In Mac OS, Sketchup  ships with Ruby 1.8 Core (not include the Standard Library) too, is it right?

Answer (score 0):

To get the pixel width and height of an image you use the `image_width` and `image_height` methods of the `Texture` object for the given `Material`.
http://www.sketchup.com/intl/en/developer/docs/ourdoc/texture.php#image_width

That's assuming when you say "image" in the context of SketchUp you mean a texture. If you want to get the info from an `Image` instance you use `Image.pixelwidth` and `Image.pixelheight`.
http://www.sketchup.com/intl/en/developer/docs/ourdoc/image.php#pixelwidth

On the other hand, if you're looking to inspect the size of a bitmap that isn't loaded into SketchUp it's more difficult since SketchUp ships with the Ruby 1.8 core and not the standard library. You could make a Ruby C Extension and do the work in C.

Comment: I have to keep the original rate between the width and height of image. So i need to know original width and original height of the image for obtaining the rate when i got the full path of image. I think functions Image.pixelwidth and Image.pixelheight are not effective in this case, because we need Image object first, and we obtain it by using function entities.add_image , but this function require width parameter and height parameter of image, we just give one parameter (width or height), another parameter depends on original rate, but i hadn't known the orginal rate before.

Comment: I read API about texture. It said that :"  Remember, textures are repeatable images that "tile" when painted on a surface". But this image doesn't contain repeatable images. 
I have just found one way to get size of image object. It is in another topic : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2450906/is-there-a-simple-way-to-get-image-dimensions-in-ruby (the secodary answer has 13 votes). But i am not sure about that.

Comment: Can you describe what you are trying to do with the image in SketchUp? Do you want it as a texture or `Image` entity? The `width` and `height` arguments of `Entities.add_image` is not the pixel dimensions - they are how large you want the image in the model.

Comment: I want it as a Image entity. I want to resize this image, but still keep the original rate between width and height of it (the rate of image before importing it into model)

Comment: If you have an `Image` entity you would only need to transform it. Just apply a uniform transformation. If you are inserting an `Image` using `Entities.add_image` then only specify the `width` argument - the `height` is optional and will be computed automatically if omitted.

Comment: Sorry for my explanation,maybe my problem is not clearly with you. I will ask it in another topic. Because this post is related with loading externel library. Here is my problem: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21941422/sketchup-api-get-the-width-and-height-of-image-with-given-path