# Sketchup API Get the width and height of image with given path

Tags: ruby, sketchup

I need to get  width and height of image with given path.
Here is my detail code

```
path  = UI.openpanel("Open Image File","/","*.jpg;*.png;*.jpeg")
if(path != nil)
  #get the original width of image
  old_width = ??????
  #get the original height of image
  old_height = ??????
  #get the orginal rate of image
  rate = old_width.to_f / old_height_to_f
  #then import image into model as a Image entity
  point = Geom::Point3d.new 0,10,0
  objImage = entities.add_image path, point , 318,318/rate
end
```

I need a way  to get value of old_width and old_height in this code with given path.
Thanks you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't need to specify the `height`, it is optional. If you specify just the `width` the `height` will be adjusted automatically based on the proportions of the image.

```
path = UI.openpanel("Open Image File", "/", "*.jpg;*.png;*.jpeg")
if !path.nil?
  point = Geom::Point3d.new(0, 10, 0)
  image = entities.add_image(path, point, 318)
end
```

Comment: Oh my god, i admit that i read API document carelessly. "If the height is not given, then it is computed from the width to preserve the aspect ratio of the image." Thanks you. I will try to read carefully

Comment: To be honest, the docs aren't the greatest all the time. They cannot be trusted 100% unfortunately.