# How to check the height and width of a image in rails before update?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a view where the user can upload his avatar picture. Im using refile and imgx. This is my view:

```
<div class="upload-avatar">
  <% if current_user.avatar %>
    <%= image_tag ix_refile_image_url(current_user, :avatar, w: 250, h: 250, fit: 'cover', bg: '0fff', fit: 'crop'), class: "avatar round-avatar", width: 130, height: 130 %>
  <% else %>
    <%= image_tag "site/blank-avatar.svg", alt: 'User Avatar', width: "130", height: "130", class: 'avatar', fit: 'cover' %>
  <% end %>
    <span class="file-upload">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-outline-green trigger-file-upload">Upload a new photo</button>
        <%= f.attachment_field :avatar, direct: true, presigned: true %>
    </span>
    </div><!-- end upload avatar -->
</div><!-- end column -->
```

In my controller, I just put a logger to check how the parameters are coming from the view. Like this:

```
 Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"RPTztPwpRRFCmyaKytJuo2USQHFWxFUpr/9KKvM80CamgfJOs9tIVGl7LFVMcAxc+R8FnxdWqgAI4gP5wBV41Q==", "user"=>{"avatar"=>"{\"id\":\"35c47de458393c007951857e5fe1296c444b40c6ee1144e39342136b84e9\",\"filename\":\"Captura de Tela 2018-11-30 às 14.52.11.png\",\"content_type\":\"image/png\",\"size\":508316}"}}
```

So I have the content type, the size, but doesn't have height and weight.

I want to, in my controller, get the weight and height of the uploaded picture. How can I do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a simple way to get image dimensions in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2450906/is-there-a-simple-way-to-get-image-dimensions-in-ruby)

Comment: Hey @mrzasa, thanks for the links. I checked it and I guess that my problem its different. I want to avoid that a User can upload a image that is not in Landscape mode. So, I want to check it on my controller (w > h). I dont think this is the case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [mini magic](https://github.com/minimagick/minimagick) gem

```
require 'mini_magick'

image = MiniMagick::Image.open(user.avatar) # or user.avatar.path
image[:width] > image[:height]
```